# Weight function

Tags: functions, optimization

Sorry if this question is badly formed or I sound like I don't know what I'm doing (I don't)

- I have a list of "jobs" each which have an amount of days until
  they are due. This can (likely) in the range of -5 to 5.
- I also have a list of people to do the jobs. (0-4) & the amount of
  time a job takes to complete.

I've attempted to write a function to attemps to give overdue jobs to person 0 and jobs due in the future to person 4 and smooth this transition between the people in between.

I.e
person 0 would have a low weight for overdue jobs and a high weight for jobs not due.
person 4 would have a high weight for due jobs and low weight for jobs in the future.

*The date in the table is the weight calculated not the time it takes*

[image]

```
(days_due * weight_I_can_tweak) + 1 + person_number

or

(-5 * 0.025) + 1 + 0
```

This is performing well for person 0, but everyone else is incorrect.

Ideally I want person 2 to have an even distribution of 1's and person 4 to have the reverse of person 0 etc.

Can anyone help push me in the correct direction?

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to make it work myself.

Thanks for anyone who did take a look.

```
weight = 0.025
people = 5
per_person = weight/(people-1)*2

function = 

(days *(weight-(per_person*person_no))+1)
```

[image]

Might not be pretty but It works.

Comment: The legendary value of *explaining* what your code does, even to [an inanimate object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging), seems to have paid off for you.  However future Readers will have difficulty discerning what objective was met or not met, and what changes you made to achieve that objective.

Comment: I said I couldn't explain it well, I find it hard to write down into words what my brain thinks, I don't know the technical terms for things and find it hard to retain that, but the process sticks. Sorry any one who does try to decipher this mess.